# getting wrong target object in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

html code

```
<div ng-click="sortOrder($event, 'fullName')" class="col-xs-2 sortable asc">
    <span>Name</span>
</div>
```

here is the js code

```
$scope.sortOrder = function(event, name) {     
        var $elem = $(event.target);
        var c = $elem.hasClass('desc') ? 'asc' : 'desc';
        $elem.removeClass('asc desc').addClass(c);
    }
```

on click of div, its adding class to inner span instead of div.col-xs-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `currentTarget` instead:

```
var $elem = $(event.currentTarget);
```

Current target is the element the event listener is created on, target is the element that triggered the event.

This means that in your case if you click on the span `target` will be the span and if you click on the div `target` will be the div. But in both cases `currentTarget` will be the div.

Another easy solution is to use `ng-class` instead.

HTML:

```
<div ng-click="changeSortOrder()" class="col-xs-2 sortable" ng-class="sortOrder">
  <span>Name</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.sortOrder = 'asc';

$scope.changeSortOrder = function () {
  $scope.sortOrder = $scope.sortOrder === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
};
```

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/0zrk7YQ7RCEVbSEj3zSh?p=preview

Example with your logic moved to directive:

JS:

```
app.directive('mySort', function () {

  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, element) {

      var defaultSortOrder = 'asc';
      element.addClass(defaultSortOrder);

      var changeSortOrder = function () {
        var newOrder = element.hasClass('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        element.removeClass('asc desc').addClass(newOrder);
      };

      element.on('click', changeSortOrder);

      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        element.off('click', changeSortOrder);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-2 sortable" my-sort>
  <span>Element 1</span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 sortable" my-sort>
  <span>Element 2</span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 sortable" my-sort>
  <span>Element 3</span>
</div>
```

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/9bf8UG6eJGW5AtlxcSgm?p=preview

Comment: I have 3,4 similar div tags, applying ng-class will change the order for all divs.

Comment: I see :) Would recommend to move it to a directive then. Just let me know if you wish for me to add an example.

Comment: I will be very thankful... if you can add an example :)

Comment: Added a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

well, I wouldn't recommend you changing the DOM element via the controller, but if you must do it (instead of a directive, which would be preferred), then you need to get the `div` element like this:

```
var $elem = $event.target.parentNode
```